# Let $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. any $n-1$-dimensional hyperplane intersects $M$ at either a point or an $n-2$-sphere. Is $M$ an $n-1$-sphere?

Tags: geometry

If $M$ is compact, then this is simple. Simply consider two points $x, y \in M$ of maximum distance. Then, maximality ensures that all planes $P$ containing $x$ and $y$ must intersect $M$ at concentric $n-2$ spheres.

It is easy to show that $M$ is closed also. So it suffices to show that $M$ is bounded. But must $M$ be bounded?

Comment: The sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ does not satisfy your hypothesis. Just take a hyperplane tangent to it. Their intersection is not an (n-2)-sphere.

Comment: @Laz Fixed! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boundedness can be achieved if we assume that the intersection loci vary continuously.

Just choose a point $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and think of the hyperplanes passing through $x$. Then this gives a function from the set of hyperplanes passing through $x$(which can be topologized as an $n-1$-sphere) measuring the maximum distance from $x$ to the intersection locus. As the domain of the function is bounded, the image is also bounded, meaning that there is a bound on the maximum distance from $x$ to the intersection locus. Then observe that there always exists a hyperplane passing through $x$ connecting an intersection point of $M$ and an hyperplane (not necessarily passing through $x$).